# Select a random object from an array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, openframeworks

I'd like to implement a function that selects a random object from an array of objects and returns it to me.  It should be something like (in C++ instead of psuedocode):

```
getRandomObject(objectList) {
    return objectList[int(random(length of objectList))];
}
```

My current code looks like this, but doesn't seem to work:

```
//definition of random selector
object getRandomObject(Object* objectList) {
    return objectList[int(ofRandom(0, sizeof(objectList)))];
};

//create a pointer for the listOfObjects
object* listOfObjects;

//create an empty object to put the randomly selected object in
object randomObject;

//later in the code, populate the array:
object* listOfObjects[] = {
    new Object(),
    new Object(),
    new Object()
};

//select random object
randomObject = getRandomObject(listOfObjects);
```

But this seems to return a segmentation fault.  A few problems I've noticed:

sizeof() returns the size of the pointer in getRandomObject, not the size of the array.  is there a good way to get the size of the array?  It might involves not using a float* pointer for the array.  Is this a good use case for vectors?

I think that much of the problem lies in how I'm creating my arrays, and not so much in how I'm selecting the random object from them.  I'm relatively new to C++ (coming from a Java background), so much of pointers / references / memory management in general is new to me.

thanks!

Comment: What happens if you change `sizeof(objectList)` with `sizeof(objectList) / sizeof(object)`?

Comment: I still get a segmentation fault, and standard output reports that sizeof(objectList) / sizeof(object) is 1 (instead of 3).

That said, without the sizeof(object) it gives sizeof(objectList) as 8, which I'm assuming is related to the size of the pointer?

Comment: Well, unless you have special needs(what are other operations you will do with the object list?) with the objects and the list I suggest to use a vector.

Comment: A vector isn't a bad idea; I just assumed that I would be able to do it with a regular array -- but apparently that just makes it more complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see one definite problem and one possible one.  The definite problem is that `sizeof(objectList)` returns the size of the `objectList` pointer, which will be 4 or 8 on most platforms.  It does not return the number of elements in the array, `objectList`.  Either pass in the length of the array or use `std::vector` or `std::array`.

The second possible problem relates to `ofRandom`.  Make sure that `ofRandom(a,b)` returns numbers >= a, but strictly < b.  If it returns values <= b, then you'll need to us `ofRandom(0, objectVector.size() - 1)`.  Typically, functions like this are written to return values strictly < b, but you should check.

Answer (score 0):

C++ has an array template class that you may want to consider using. Check out the documentation here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/

This type has a method, `size()`, that will return the length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

> **When the sizeof operator is applied to an array, it yields the total
>   number of bytes in that array,** not the size of the pointer represented
>   by the array identifier.
>   [Quote](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s7x1k91%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

So you take the space alocated for your whole array and divide by the memory need just for one element: `sizeof(objectList) / sizeof(*objectList)`.

Answer (score 0):

Mr Fooz noticed issues that cause a segfault.

Other *compilation* issues are:

`listOfObjects` is declared with 2 different types:  `object*` and `object*[3]` while `getRandomObject` expects a type `Object*`.

`listOfObjects[]` contains elements of type `object*` while `getRandomObject` reads elements of type `Object` and returns `object`.